# Firebase Cloud Messaging: error "SenderId mismatch" when sending from Google Compute Engine

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I am getting a `SenderId mismatch` error (documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)) when sending a message for **Firebase Cloud Messaging**, using the **Admin SDK** (in Go) running on a **Google Compute Engine** VM.

My **GCE** and **Firebase** are two separate GCP projects.

I am currently using the **default service account** of my GCE VM, which I gave the **Editor** role for the **Firebase** project.

My interpretation is that the sender should be the Firebase project, while it is instead the GCE project.

How can I fix this issue?

For reference, this is my Go code:

```
ctx := context.Background()
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}
client, err := app.Messaging(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error getting Messaging client: %v\n", err)
}
...
response, err := client.Send(ctx, message)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution!

I had to specify the Firebase GCP project id in the configuration

```
ctx := context.Background()
config := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "xxxxxxxx"}
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}
```